# how to delete multiple objects in a list of objects through its properties

Tags: c#

I'm back with another question regarding objects again.
Do note I'm just one month into programming in general so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

Right now I'm doing some homework that has me design a library class and a books class. This library is supposed to store a number of books. I'm supposed to manipulate this list of objects with some methods. Most of the methods I know how to design except one. I am supposed to search this list for all books with a certain author and delete them. I don't know how to approach this. I am able to delete singular objects from the list through the properties of the book class but I dont know how to delete multiple objects of it.

```
    class Library
    {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> list = new List<Book>();
    public List<Book> foundBooks = new List<Book>();

    public Library(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    //Library Methods
    public void AddBook(Book book)
    {
        list.Add(book);
    }

    public void PrintBookInfo(Book book)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Title: "+ book.Title);
        Console.WriteLine("Author " +book.Author);
        Console.WriteLine("Publisher: "+ book.Publisher);
        Console.WriteLine("Release Date: " + book.ReleaseDate.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("ISBN: " + book.ISBN);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void PrintAllBooks()
    {
        foreach (Book book in list)
        {
            PrintBookInfo(book);
        }
    }

    public Book SearchForBook(string name)
    {

        foreach (Book book in list)
        {
            if (book.Author == name)
            {
                PrintBookInfo(book);
                return book;         

            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    public void DeleteBook(Book book)// this is the method im using to delete objects but I don't know how to extend this.
    {
        list.Remove(book);
    }
}
```

Here is my book class

```
class Book
{
    //Properties
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }  
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public int ISBN { get; set; }


    public Book(string Title, 
        string Author,
        string Publisher,
        DateTime ReleaseDate,
        int ISBN)
    {
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Author = Author;
        this.Publisher = Publisher;
        this.ReleaseDate = ReleaseDate;
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
    }
}
```

Finally my main so far:

```
        class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var library = new Library("Yishun Regional Library");
        var bookOne = new Book("Harry Potter", "JK Rowling", "UK", DateTime.Today, 1165);
        var bookTwo = new Book("Eragon", "Paolini", "Netherlands", DateTime.Today, 2565);
        var bookThree = new Book("Harry", "JK Rowling", "UK", DateTime.Today, 1145);

        library.AddBook(bookOne);
        library.AddBook(bookTwo);
        library.AddBook(bookThree);

        Console.WriteLine("Hello Welcome To Yishun Library. Take a look at the books Availabe.");
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (Book book in library.list)
        {
            library.PrintBookInfo(book);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        string name;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter name of author: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        var bookFound = library.SearchForBook(name);

        library.DeleteBook(bookFound);
        Console.WriteLine("Current list of books: \n");

        library.PrintAllBooks();
    }
```

One way I thought to implement this is to create an array of books found and then delete the books using foreach method but I don't know how to implement this. Or rather I quickly found out that you cant manipulate the data using foreach. Any help would be appreciated thanks! ;]

Comment: When deleting from any List<> object you have to start at the end of the list and move toward the beginning.  If you have a list 1,2,3,4 and you delete '2' you end up skipping '3' when you move forward through the list.  So I use for(int index = myList.Count -1; index >= 0; index--).

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use `for` loop instead of `foreach` one and loop *backward*:

```
  for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (String.Equals(list[i].Author, "AuthorToDelete"))
          list.RemoveAt(i);
```

In case of looping *forward* the scheme is more complex:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count;)
      if (String.Equals(list[i].Author, "AuthorToDelete"))
          list.RemoveAt(i); 
      else
          i += 1;
```

Or just call (is it accepted in homework?)

```
  list.RemoveAll(book => String.Equals(book.Author, "AuthorToDelete"));
```

Comment: Wow that actually looks rather to easy to implement! I do admit though, I would have never thought about it that way. Thanks for the insight! Anyways, havent touched Linq yet. Should do so in a couple of weeks so that syntax is foreign to me.

Comment: @Nate: you're welcome! Sometimes an old good procedural code is what we often overlook.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Library` class:

```
public void DeleteBooksByAuthor(string authorName)
{
    list.RemoveAll(x => x.Author == authorName);
}
```

Comment: you should use equals to compare string

Comment: Hmmm... Why is that?

Comment: @nmtuan The results will be different only when one of the values is `null`, which is not the case.

Comment: if Author isnt a string it could go bam

Comment: Author is a string. See `Book` class definition.

Comment: string a = "a";
object b = ('a').ToString();
(a == b) //false, Tested on NET4.6.1

Comment: True, but there is no such code in the OP post. Only `strings`, and no `objects`.

Comment: Maybe it just my preference :) your answer is correct, just a matter of good practice to me, probably because im used to doing java

Answer (score 0):

Hi use the below code in your class. It would handle null check on your list object as well

```
    public void DeleteBooksByAuthor(string authorName)
    {
        list?.RemoveAll(x => x?.Author == authorName);
    }
```

Comment: Often `.?` (both in `list?.RemoveAll` and in `x?.Author`) *mask* error: better choice is to have `NullPointerException` thrown and *debug* the routine *early*.